# What route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 mean?

Tags: route, cisco

when starting Cisco AnyConnect I get:

```
$route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 cscotun0
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ppp0
10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cscotun0
10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 cscotun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ppp0
172.16.50.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cscotun0
172.16.50.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cscotun0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.77.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cscotun0
192.168.153.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cscotun0
192.168.153.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
213.177.15.200  10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 ppp0
```

while when stopped I have:

```
$route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ppp0
10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ppp0
172.16.50.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.153.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
```

q1: What means:

```
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 cscotun0
```

While connected with Cisco AnyConnect I lose all Internet access which I only guess it has something with this line.

q2: what routing change should I do in order to have Cisco AnyConnect routes accessible while also have Internet access? I can do nothing related to the server I'm connecting to with Cisco AnyConnect.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. The router you are connecting to via Cisco Anyconnect is blocking internet traffic. Do you have access and necessary permissions to make changes to the configuration of the vpn server?

Comment: I have no access to make changes on the vpn server. But wouldn't it possible on the client to just remove that route?

Comment: So I have found a lot of information about your issue. Check out these posts [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106304/route-add-no-longer-works-when-i-connected-to-vpn-via-cisco-anyconnect-client) [2](https://superuser.com/questions/284709/how-to-allow-local-lan-access-while-connected-to-cisco-vpn) [3](https://superuser.com/questions/380852/trick-out-cisco-vpn-with-routes) What it looks like is that AnyConnect takes control of your routing table. You can modify this behavior but that depends on your goals.